# Why are the changes of instance variables of Parent class reflected in Child class?

Tags: java, inheritance, instance-variables

If i change the instance variable of parent class the changes are reflected in Child class, even though they have different identityHashCodes. Why does this happen?

I've tried creating child's own instance variables, which then don't reflect the changes because of reference type calls. Also, i've first called the child method which prints the instance variables then called the parent's method which does some changes and then print. this proves that the changes are done dynamically, not at compile time. I've tried using both the constructors which didn't do any major difference to my problem.

```
class Library{
        int count = 500;
        int years = 70;
        Library(){
                System.out.println(" Constructor library ");
        }
        Library(int count,int years){
                this.count = count;
                this.years = years;
                System.out.println(" Constructor library ");
        }
        void libraryInfo(){
                count++;
                System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(count));
                System.out.println(" Years " + years);
                System.out.println(" Count " + count);
        }
}
class Book extends Library{
        //int count = 500;
        //int years = 70;
        Book(){
                super(700,80);
           //   super();            
        }
        void libraryInfo(){
                super.libraryInfo();
                System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(count));
                System.out.println(" Years " + years);
                System.out.println(" Count " + count);
                //super.libraryInfo();
        }
        public static void main(String args[]){
                Book b = new Book();
                b.libraryInfo();
        }

}
```

Expected results are changes are restricted to the parent class only. 
Actual results show changes reflect to the Child object also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to explain it more simply with a weird example but it might help to understand the concept.

Say a father has purchased a bike for his son, then his son can say that it is his bike (as he has inherited it from his father) and he can ride it whenever he wants.

Now say there was 1 liter of petrol left in bike and father gets its tank full, then when his son will see the bike next time it will be full for him as well.

I hope that helps to understand.

Comment: I get this, but isn't the bike the same for both of them? Here the count is giving us different identityHashCodes,which may mean they're different objects

Comment: @0ne0rZer0 `System.identityHashCode(Object x)` This method expects an Object as a parameter. You are passing an `int` variable to it i.e. `int count`. Try it with wrapper class `Integer`. It might be something related to auto boxing of int to Integer.

Comment: I tried it with a Instance variable of string, could you tell me how do I use wrapper class to do the same?

Comment: @0ne0rZer0 Corresponding to each primitive data type there exists one wrapper class. Like in place of `int`, I said `Integer`. There wasn't any need to use `String`, you could have achieved the same by `Integer` as well. You can read more about wrapper classes [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class)

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a "parent object" and a "child object". There's just "an object".

A class is (more or less) just a blueprint for creating an object.  With inheritance, some of the blueprint is written in the parent and some of the blueprint is written in the child.

In your case, your object is a Book. The Book happens to have some characteristics it inherited from the Library, but it's still a Book.  There's not a Book and a Library as distinct objects.  (Which is a pretty weird inheritance model: libraries have very little in common with books)

Answer (score 1):

I think your main confusion lies in the understanding of System.identityHashCode, as it's comment says:

```
 Returns the same hash code for the given object as
 would be returned by the default method hashCode(),
 whether or not the given object's class overrides
 hashCode().
```

If your change parameter from count to this, they will return the same value. You can define count in Book class to override parent if you'd like to keep them separated.